# returning expected results from Google

Tags: asp.net, google-custom-search

I am building automation system to get news related to specific subject from Google. 
First, I used the deprecated version [Google Web Search](https://developers.google.com/web-search/) which have less features than expected. because of that, I decided to move to the new Custom Search Engine. As you may know, [Custom Search Engine](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) doesn't return expected results.. even when using custom country domain.
 
I tried to scrap google results, but I see some developers saying that it's not legal and google will catch me! so, **do i have any other options for getting expected results?**


**Note:** I am using custom search engine to search the web, not for only one website.

Comment: Define _expected results_ ....

Comment: @EdSF different and unrelated results than what you get when you search using your browser